# Passar dados de um gridview para outro gridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

Tenho uma datagridview1 que busca na base de dados os dados e mostra as informações, quero que ao clicar no botão adicionar ele pegue a linha selecionada na primeira datagridview1 e passe para outra datagridview2.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Como faz o binding dos dados para o primeiro DataGrid?

Comment: 'var source =  new BindingSource();
    List<Dados> dados = DadosBo.GetUsuario(Usuario.idUsuario); // Pega todos os dados do usuario.
   source.datasource = dados;
   datagridview.datasource = source;'

Comment: Por que não captura o click na célula, verifica qual ID do `Dado`, busca no banco e vai alimentando uma lista que servirá de binding para o segundo DataGrid?

Answer (score 2):

Coloquei uma `List<string>` apenas de exemplo, mas a ideia é essa:

```
    List<string> Selecionados = new List<string>();
    private void buttonAdicionar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count >0)
        {
            string item = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["ColunaItem"].Value.ToString();
            //Adiciona outras propriedades, quantidades, etc...
            Selecionados.Add(item);
            //update no dataGridView2
        }
    }
```